# What is the cosine of two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

For calculating a cosine one needs a right-angled triangle.
So is the cosine of two vectors the cosine of any right-angled triangle that you can "build" in some way from these vectors ?

[triangle created with two vectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRVS2.png)

Comment: Look up dot product to find a meaningful definition of two vectors involving cosine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it refers to the cosine of the angle between these two vectors. It is closely related to the inner product of these two vectors:
$$
\vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}=|\vec{a}|\cdot|\vec{b}|\cdot \cos \sphericalangle (\vec{a},\vec{b})
$$

Comment: See the "law of cosines" ... for cosines one does not need a right triangle.

Comment: What does the $\cos \angle(x,y)$ mean? I assume it is the dot product definition.

Comment: Yes, and it means the angle between the two vectors.